# ScrollView show one item at a time

Tags: android, listview, scrollview

I have a problem in my ScrollView. I want to display a ListView items starting from under the toolbar to the Button placed at the bottom in my layout. This does not work, my ScrollView shows one item at a time.

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/ScrollView01"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        tools:showIn="@layout/activity_wigeo_scan"
        tools:context=".application.WiGeoScan">

        <TextView android:text="@string/wifi_scan"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:id="@+id/content_wigeo_scan_textView_title"
            android:textSize="35dp"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

        <Space
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="10dp"
            android:layout_below="@id/content_wigeo_scan_textView_title"
            android:id="@+id/space0" />

        <ListView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/space0"
            android:id="@+id/content_wigeo_scan_listView"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"/>

    </RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 1):

Change your `ScrollView` with this.

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/ScrollView01"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
```

Comment: then please accept this answer so other can also knows.